# How to force chrome to open links in system browser

Tags: google-chrome, .desktop, default-browser

I'm running a 'desktop web app' for Fastmail and for reasons that I can't recall, I could only get this to run in Google Chrome (chromium or FF didn't work).

Unfortunately this means that any links I click in my email open in a new Fastmail app window (a normal tabbed Google Chrome window), instead of opening in my preferred Firefox, which is set as the default browser.

Is there any way around this?

Here's the desktop entry, `SingleMainWindow` doesn't appear to have any effect:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=FastMail
Exec=/opt/google/chrome-unstable/chrome --disable-extensions --force-device-scale-factor=2 --app=https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/
TryExec=/opt/google/chrome-unstable/chrome
Icon=~/.local/share/applications/fastmail-icon.svg
StartupWMClass=www.fastmail.com__mail_Inbox
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
SingleMainWindow=true
```